# How to view text encode in Japanese android

Tags: android, json, view, decode, encode

I have a api and json format like bellow:

```
{
 status: 200,
 messages: "OK",
 results: [
  {
   id: 3,
   code: "just_item",
   name: "åäºŒæ¡è¥¿ä¸€ä¸ç›®"
  },
  {
   id: 4,
   code: "all_item",
   name: "åäºŒæ¡è¥¿ä¸€ä¸ç›®"
  }
 ]
}
```

I want to view text "åäºŒæ¡è¥¿ä¸€ä¸ç›®" in Android APP like text "全商品"

Comment: try utf-8 encoding : <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: I want to show text in android app, but app show text "åäºŒæ¡è¥¿ä¸€ä¸ç›®", Thanks

Comment: the data you get from browser is not formatted then how you will get correct in app?

Comment: where you get the text? if you copy paste the "åäºŒæ¡è¥¿ä¸€ä¸ç›®" string from somewhere to your app, there is no way to put it back.

Comment: fixed: add  content_type :json, "application/json;charset=UTF-8"

Answer (score 1):

try UTF-8 encode

```
  HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
  HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
  HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "UTF-8");
  params.setBooleanParameter("http.protocol.expect-continue", false);
  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);

  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Your_URL);
  HttpResponse http_response= httpclient.execute(httppost);

  HttpEntity entity = http_response.getEntity();
  String jsonText = EntityUtils.toString(entity, HTTP.UTF_8);
 // your response should appear in proper way 
  Log.i("Response", jsonText);
```